# `obj.operator+=(rhs)` vs. `obj += rhs`

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class test
{
public:
    int i = 0;
    test& operator+=(const test &rhs)
    {
        i += rhs.i;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    test t;
    test rhs;
    rhs.i = 10;
    // what's the difference betwen these 2?
    t.operator+=(rhs);
    t += rhs;
}
```

Is there any difference between `t.operator+=(rhs);` and `t += rhs;` here? I've always used the latter, and have never thought much about the former. Is there any advantage to using the former over the latter?

Comment: Semantically, they are equivalent, apart (depending on compiler version/standard) order of evaluation (e.g. sequencing of evaluating `t` and `rhs`)).   In your case, when the compiler encounters the expression `t += rhs`, it recognises the existence of `test::operator+=()` so, after evaluating `t` and `rhs`, emits the same code as it would for a call of `t.operator+=(rhs)`.

Comment: It'll be better to tag a C++ version in the question because C++17 alters the operation order a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, there is no difference. When you write:

`t += rhs`

the compiler will process it as:

`t.operator+=(rhs)`

So, the two calls as just different syntaxes for the same call.

Comment: "*No difference whatsoever.*" Incorrect. C++17 changed the order of operations so that `t += rhs` will evaluate the `rhs` operand *before* `t`. Whereas `t.operator+=(rhs)` sequences `t` before `rhs`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Is this change relevant outside of exceptions?

Comment: @NicolBolas not able to identify the difference as you mentioned

Comment: @anonuser01: if `rhs` or `t` have side effects, (such as evil construct `t += ++t`)